# Does BeginSend<IList<ArraySegment....) perform atomic send of all the ArraySegments?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

The Socket class in .NET exposes the following method:

```
Socket.BeginSend Method (IList<ArraySegment<Byte>>, SocketFlags, AsyncCallback, Object)
```

I have a BufferManager class that returns `ArraySegment<byte>` of a specified, constant size of 2kB. Now I have a message to be sent, let's say it is 10kB large, so I can use 5 preallocated buffers to store this message and call `Socket.BeginSend(IList<ArraySegment>>...)`. Will this message be sent atomically, as it would be when I would just use just `byte[]` (ie. several parallel BeginSend operations wouldn't mix messages on the remote site)?

Edit: to clarify - I'm using TCP/IP socket and my program calls BeginSend from several threads simultaneously.
Let's say we have two lists of array segments:
L1: a1 a2 a3
L2: b1 b2 b3
Now I call BeginSend(L1...) and BeginSend (L2...) from two threads at the same time. I want to know whether those two lists won't get mixed on the remote side and I won't read something like: a1 b1 b2 a2 b3 a3.

Comment: What do you mean by "atomic" ?  The sequence will be guaranteed, but I don't exepct this to be thread-safe.

Comment: Sockets don't know anything about the concept of "atomic". They are very low-level. If you need such guarantees, then you need to increase the level of abstraction and use something like WCF.

Comment: @John Saunders I know the socket doesn't have the notion of atomicity, but when I call Send(byte[]) I'm sure that the bytes sent will arrive "uninterrupted" by any other message and in the correct order (though they may come in several TCP packets and the other and depending on the MTA settings). I just want to know whether I can count on the same behavior when using BeginSend (IList<ArraySegment>)

Comment: @Henk Holterman so the sequence is guaranteed - When I call two BeginSend I can be certain that the remote side won't receive let's say: two elements from the first BeginSend, that all elements of the other one, and the rest of elements from the first list?

Comment: @paszczi So let's break down your question a little further;  If you *could* guarantee atomicity, it would imply what the first thread that writes would have to some how get into a queue for the underlying socket, grab hold of the socket when given a chance, and then hold on to it while the waiting for its buffers to flush enough times send out all of your byte sequences.   Such a mechanism is certainly *not* something I would hope to see implemented in something as low-level as Socket.

Comment: @Armentage - no,I don't want to grab socket directly, neither to get in its queue.I want to send data atomically to socket's buffer so that the OS can do all the rest. It's exactly how BeginSend (byte[]) works-when you call it, you may be certain that, without any additional synchronization, all the data is placed in one piece and no other thread can get in the way-I have a server that has been running for almost 3 years, serving hundreds of clients and I never did any synchronization on sending.I assume that BeginSend (List<ArraySegment>) exposes the same behavior,but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

All a BufferManager does is maintain a set of fixed blocks of memory for you to use.  The BufferManager has no affect on the concurrency of the bytes, or how they are used in anyway at all what so ever.  From the MSDN documentation:

> You can use the BufferManager class to manage a buffer pool. The pool and its buffers are created when you instantiate this class and destroyed when the buffer pool is reclaimed by garbage collection. Every time you need to use a buffer, you take one from the pool, use it, and return it to the pool when done. This process is much faster than creating and destroying a buffer every time you need to use one.

The BufferManager is just a convenient way of avoiding calls to new[] and then waiting for the GC to destroy the blocks.  When you are done sending these blocks, make sure you call BlockManager.ReturnBuffer, or those bytes will be unavailable for future messages, and will linger until your BufferManager  itself is GC'd.  If it's going to be along lived BufferManager, and you are sending a lot of messages using those buffers, you will likely leak huge amounts of memory.

Comment: My question was not about the thread-safety of BufferManager, I've provided this piece of information to create some context.